# Visual Studio Stuck in Weird Mode Causing Keyboard Issues

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This has happened to me in other versions of Visual Studio, but it' been happening a lot lately in VS.NET 2010. I'm sure the fix is simple, but I do not know what it is and it's driving me nuts.

I'll be working in VS.NET and then all of a sudden I can't click with the mouse to go to a point in the code. I don't get the cursor. All it does is highlight entire words in grey whenever I try to change the cursor position. And then typing doesn't work or it's quirky. The only thing I've noticed is in the VS.NET status bar. It says something like "...waiting for second key stroke after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>...". I know <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is a VS.NET shortcut, so I press another key in the key combo just to try to get out of this mode. Today I pressed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it said, this is not a valid key combo. I was expecting to get out of the weird mode I was in, but nothing changed.

The only way I can fix it is to close VS.NET and load it up again. Not ideal and a waste of time.

Maybe it's not even related to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> key stroke combo, but it's the only thing I notice when I'm stuck in this weird keyboard limbo mode. Like I said I'm sure it's simple to get out of this mode, just not sure how. Googling hasn't produced much.

Ideas anyone?

Yours truly,

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: I get this sometimes too.  Usually I only have to close the document I'm working in and reopen it, though; only occasionally the whole IDE.  I hadn't connected it to keyboard commands....interesting.  I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: This was a bug in the RC release.  If you have the RTM edition and service pack 1 applied then post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Hans Passant - I'm running VS.NET 2010 Ultimate version 10.0.40219 SP 1Rel. I guess I need to post it to MS a a bug.

Comment: This problem persists and hit me today with Visual Studio 2019 16.1.5. I think some code somewhere is not resetting the state of the ctrl-key in the IDE somewhere. It happens and sometimes can't be cleared even by restarting the IDE. :( Time to try reboot?

Comment: For me, restarting VS solved the issue.

Answer (score 14):

I have been able to clear this is the past by doing a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to another page, then return to the original page.  Seems to work without having to close the page.

Comment: This keyboard is still happening with an installation of VS2013 that I use. Thanks for your tip Laramie - it works for me.

Comment: Still happens in VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is exactly related to your problem but I have also experienced strange behavior in Visual Studio 2010. I have tracked it down to the following:

<kbd>SHIFT + WIN</kbd> puts the editor in some kind of auto selection mode. Wherever I click the mouse button, the text between cursor position and the click gets selected. To get out of it press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

<kbd>CONTROL + WIN</kbd> puts the editor in a mode where it treats every mouse click as if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is pressed. To get out of it, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

The keys mentioned above has to be pressed simultaneous for this to work. I don't think this has to do with Windows Sticky Keys as I have that function disabled. It seems to be a Windows feature since this works system wide and is not isolated to Visual Studio only.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the problem you were experiencing but I had a problem where My plus key suddenly started acting like a mouse click.

At first I thought I might have a modifier stuck down but after a bit more experimenting I discovered this was also the case in other programs aswell.

After some googling it turns out I must have accidentally turned on `mouse keys`.

You can switch this on and off by using `shift-alt + num lock`.  When you switch it off it also switches off the num lock (but switching on doesn't toggle it).  This is possibly off-topic but I thought it might help people who were googling for the same thing.